# What are the benefits of using statsD with cloud-watch-agent over AWS SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, statsd

We are currently sending metrics to Cloudwatch for every request using AWS SDK(putMetric call).

I was exploring another solution and there is one where we can use statsD with an cloudwatch-agent which will push metrics to Cloudwatch every x seconds.

What is the advantage of using statsD here? Will it be cost-effective? Will it it be fast? Should I even use statsD? Are there any alternative better than statsD?